# PL/SQL INSERT DATA TO TABLE IN ORACLE APEX

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I created a blank page and inserted textfields and button which will serve as a form. I want to display the inserted data from user once the button save is clicked, and the data will also show on the interactive grid below the page. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest another approach: use the Wizard to create *Report with a Form on a table*. It will create an Interactive Report (and you'll use it to review data stored into a table) and a Form (you'll use to insert new records and to update/delete existing ones).

Apex does **everything** for you; you'll only have to make it *pretty* because it'll *work* "as is". With your approach, you'll have to program everything yourself.